# Get isCreateable() value of an object

Tags: apex

I am trying to see whether user has the create permission for a particular object.

I managed to get till here:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult s = test__C.sObjectType.getDescribe();
```

And on debug i can see below as well:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult[getKeyPrefix=a0C;
getLabel=test;
getLabelPlural=tests;
getName=test__c;
isAccessible=true;
isCreateable=true;
isCustom=true;
isCustomSetting=false;
isDeletable=true;
isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
isFeedEnabled=true;
isMergeable=false;
isQueryable=true;
isSearchable=true;
isUndeletable=true;
isUpdateable=true;]
```

How do i now check against isCreateable() here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult s = test__C.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Boolean isCreateable = s.isCreateable();
```

Comment: I have been trying to do the same,but will give me a compile error.
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Schema.DescribeSObjectResult].isCreatable()

Comment: d'oh! I had a typo, it's `s.isCreateable()`, with an e.

Comment: oh!!! i just realised i have been doing the same typo all this time :D